# Truncate text in scalable content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I divided page into 2 parts which I have done it using 'w-50' bootstrap(4) css class.

All page items(components) are already created and designed and they work as expected except the text(*Lorem impsum dolor sit amet*) which should be truncated based on available space.

I have listed the type of components marked orange in uploaded image.
*select -> span -> img(star in this case) -> div(fixed size)*

When all the other elements select, img(star), div(fixed) takes their respective widths, we have to truncate our span(lorem ipsum).

Could you please provide any solution or suggest a topic which should be investigated to archive the result expected?

```
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/umf6nzL3/6/
```

[image]

Comment: Hi There ...What exactly do you mean by trucated. And could you also share your code on jsfiddle. Would like to have a look there :)

Comment: Hi @ImranRafiqRather. Truncate text it means text truncation using CSS's text-overflow property and etc. If you look at the uploaded image(i.e. exactly lorem ipsum text) then you visually understand what text truncation means. Sharing current code on jsfiddle will take some time I suppose. So I will share it when I'll finish with that.

Comment: No problem. I understood where you are coming from. Once you have your code on codepen or jsfiddle. Feel free to drop me a message, that's where I can actually see what is going on.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather I have created JSFiddle where similar page with similar components are included.
https://jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/umf6nzL3/6/

Comment: Great ! let me see :)

Comment: Have provided the solution for your problem. You may adjust the width property in the added CSS as per your convenience. I just put 120px to show the demo. And do Vote and Accept the answer if this helps you to resolve your query :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Created my Custom Scenario's  to resolve the Problem.  Apart from adding some additional CSS, have used a bit of Javascript as well to meet the required conditions.

**Working Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Account Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      select {
        width: 100px;
      }
      .fixed-right-aligned {
        flex-basis: 330px;
      }

      .left-actions {
        background-color: #fa4567;
      }

      .right-actions {
        background-color: #13a352;
      }

      .left-content {
        background-color: #4667fa;
      }

      .right-content {
        background-color: #67fa46;
      }

      /* --- Added CSS --- */
      .wrapper-aem {
        height: 20px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-right: 5px;
      }

      .three-dots {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="h-100 w-100 p-0">
      <div class="d-flex w-100">
        <div class="d-flex w-100">
          <div class="w-50 left-actions">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <div
                class="d-flex align-items-center left-actions-content flex-grow-1"
              >
                <select>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                </select>

                <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-grow-1">
                  <div class="wrapper-aem flex-grow-1">
                    <span class="lorem-content">
                      Lorem ipsum There are no accidents Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </span>
                    <span class="three-dots">...</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="block d-flex align-items-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-icon info-icon" type="button">
                      <svg
                        height="16pt"
                        viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511"
                        width="16pt"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"
                          fill="#ffc107"
                        />
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div
                class="d-flex p-1 align-items-center justify-content-end fixed-right-aligned"
              >
                Fixed sized toolbar
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w-50 right-actions">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <p>Any content goes here</p>
              </div>

              <div
                class="d-flex p-1 align-items-center justify-content-end fixed-right-aligned"
              >
                <span>Fixed sized toolbar</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="w-50 left-content">
          <span> Left content </span>
        </div>
        <div class="w-50 right-content">
          <span> Right content </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
        const loremWrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper-aem");

        // I have used the resize handler for testing purposes, It may or may not be needed (decide as per your requirement)
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
          handleContentBehaviour();
        });

        const handleContentBehaviour = () => {
          if (window.innerWidth > 1366) {
            document.querySelector(".three-dots").style.display =
              "inline-block";
          } else {
            document.querySelector(".three-dots").style.display = "none";
          }
        };
        handleContentBehaviour();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have already defined a class as yours but unfortunately I don't know how correctly/easily define width to each specific screen size. As my understanding I need to define different width per screen sizes(i.e 1366px, 1367px, 1368px and etc.) which is hard to maintain.

Comment: Hey Bro, I got a question, I think your problem is solved if I get you answer. You just want the text(Lorem impsum dolor sit amet) to be truncated but based on the available space without touching any other code. Am I right Mate ?

Comment: Absolutely yes. That is exactly my issue

Comment: Just give me a moment. :)

Comment: So currently you are facing problem's on smaller screens as the browser window is shrinked. Correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: Problem is common. i.e. if not resized correctly for big screens it will take less space  than it's expected, but in small screens it can take more space that available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226209/discussion-between-aemloviji-and-imran-rafiq-rather).

Comment: You updated answer seems works. I will test it thoroughly and accept the answer if it will behave as expected in all situations.

Comment: Life is all about being kind and helping one another. I will be more than happy if my time spend on this problem reaches to its conclusion.  Stay Blessed Mate <3

Comment: Hi there. Hope u are doing great :)

Comment: @AEMLoviji: Do please take some time to accept the answer and vote for it. This will help other developers solve their issues with the same query. Thank you